# How To Keep A Form On Top Of Others In VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, z-order, topmost

I'm working on a application that has a main form and a floating form that contains some useful tools. I want it to be on top of my main form. so I tried `ToolForm.TopMost = True` but when i go to another application it is still on top. how can I implement it in my app? being the top most just forms of the application.

**Something Like Find And Replace Window in Visual Studio**

Comment: why dont you try `me.topmost=true`.using `formname.topmost=true` makes it on top of any other applications,so try alternative so it will be on top of you application only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call the `Show` method on the floating window, you can pass the main form as the owner window.  For instance:

```
Dim floating As New FloatingForm()
floating.Show(Me)
```

That will cause the floating window to always stay in front of its owner window, but it will not stop the owner window from continuing to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
  Dim yourfrmTools As New Form()
  parentForm.AddOwnedForm(yourfrmTools)
  yourfrmTools.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CreateMyTopMostForm()
   ' Create lower form to display. 
   Dim bottomForm As New Form()
   ' Display the lower form Maximized to demonstrate effect of TopMost property.
   bottomForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
   ' Display the bottom form.
   bottomForm.Show()
   ' Create the top most form. 
   Dim topMostForm As New Form()
   ' Set the size of the form larger than the default size.
   topMostForm.Size = New Size(300, 300)
   ' Set the position of the top most form to center of screen.
   topMostForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
   ' Display the form as top most form.
   topMostForm.TopMost = True
   topMostForm.Show()
End Sub 'CreateMyTopMostForm
```